# Когда инициализируются статические поля класса? Что будет если при инициализации статического поля сгенерируется исключение?

Tags: c++, классы, исключения, c++11, c++17

Данный код сработает до запуска main()? Что будет если при инициализации m_filed произойдет исключение? Когда вызовется деструктор m_field?

```
class Example {

private:
static int m_field;
}

int Example::m_field = 0;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сколько времени нужно, чтоб набросать вот такой тестовый код

```
struct Info
{
    Info() { cout << "ctor Info\n"; }
    ~Info() { cout << "dtor Info\n"; }
};

struct Test
{
    static Info ii;
};

Info Test::ii;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    cout << "main()\n";
}
```

и получить ответы почти на все ваши вопросы? :) Вы не верите разработчикам компиляторов? :)

Ну, а в ответ на все неперехваченные исключения вызывается функция `terminate()`.

Чтоб убедиться — исправьте код выше так:

```
Info()  {
    set_terminate([](){cout << "Unhandled exception\n" << flush; });
    cout << "ctor Info\n"; throw 0; 
}
```

Comment: Поскольку порядок вызова конструкторов объектов, создаваемых до вызова main в разных единицах компиляции, не определен, то я не был бы на 100% уверен, что `cout` вообще отработает в любой  реализации

Comment: А в дестркторе set_terminate(old_terminate) .наверное

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А смысл? Деструктор все равно вызывается, когда программа завершена...

Comment: @avp Теоретически да, но... «Теория, мой друг, суха, но зеленеет жизни древо» (с) Сами знаете кто :)

Comment: А чего из лямбды потёрли вызов `std::abort`? Без него поток выполнения выйдет обычным образом из лямбды, а это UB.

Comment: @wololo Для краткости и выразительности. Для понимания происходящего это несущественно.